# Are text editors that use Markdown by detault safer than other text editors

Tags: php, security, xss, ckeditor, markdown

I'm familiar with CKEditor which converts bold text to its HTML tags `<strong>`. Other editors (like the editor on this site) use Markdown formatting and I see bold text wrapped in stars instead of HTML like this `**text**`.

Sp does this mean that using a markdown editor protects you by default from any XSS in that user input? I think yes (which is the the main reason I want to use a markdown editor and not ckeditor), but want to double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: http://michelf.com/weblog/2010/markdown-and-xss/

It doesn't escape XSS on default

Answer (score 3):

There are no XSS safe client side editors.  Even if the editor does not allow you to insert arbitrary HTML, it is trivially easy for someone to bypass the editor and submit arbitrary HTML.

The only safe solution is to sanitize the HTML on the server.

Comment: Exactly. A better question would be whether supporting **only** raw markdown posts would give you better protection against XSS (compared to html entry) and I think the answer would be yes.

Comment: @Darien: No, you can inline HTML within your markdown, so you would still have to parse the markdown to strip out HTML.

Comment: @Darien `only raw markdown posts` means that the user types `**bold text**` but it doesn't get converted to **bold text**, it stays as is and the readers read it as `**bold text**`? If this is what you mean, I don't think that would be very visually appealing. It does no styling at all, and is kind of pointless.

Comment: What I meant is that you store the eight-character string "`**bold**`" inside your database, and show it inside text editors, etc. The only time it ever becomes the eleven-character "`<b>bold</b>`" is at the end when it's being displayed by a view-component.

This is in contrast to converting it during input-time and storing the eleven-character version... Because then when the user wants to edit their post, your form-submit now needs to accept < and > symbols and intelligently choose when to escape them, etc.